# Can you convert a Wi-Fi card to Bluetooth protocol?

Tags: wireless-networking, bluetooth

Hear me out. So I have a Wi-Fi card, and because it is long-range I want to use it as bluetooth. Can I do it? It is also significantly easier to find high-power Wi-Fi cards rather than high-power Bluetooth cards. Can I use the Wi-Fi cards to communicate via Bluetooth, e.g. convert them to bluetooth?

Comment: RF chip is almost identical. So rewrite its firmware and you will get what you want. It also needs to change RF protocol so if your RF chip does not allow that you have to get other card. But I afraid you will get the same tange as for common Bluetooth devices. Because of timings.

Answer (score 4):

No. The Bluetooth and Wifi physical layer protocols (as implemented by the radios) are too different due to their design goals.

They operate over the same frequency range, and may be able to share an antenna, but the actual hardware doing the work of putting data on-air is too different.

Bluetooth uses 80 1MHz channels, in the 2.4GHz band Wifi uses 13 much wider channels. You might think that means that it would be easy for a wifi radio to use just 1MHz, but it doesn't work that way. The transmitter is tuned and band-passed to use a higher bandwidth and may well swamp a whole load of bluetooth channels making communication nearly impossible.

Wifi is in general a lot more complicated and the radio electronics work very differently, they cannot be reprogrammed to work as if they are a different radio.

For detailed information on the "physical" layer differences see [Bluetooth Physical Layer](https://www.rfwireless-world.com/Tutorials/Bluetooth-physical-layer.html) and [WLAN Physical Layer](https://www.rfwireless-world.com/Articles/Overview_of_11a_PHY_layer.html).